# How to get minimum value in pyMongo

Tags: mongodb, python

I have a collection with several fields, and I'd like to get the minimum value from one. I know a command for getting the max value:

```
collection.find_one(sort=[("myfield", -1)])["myfield"]
```

but not one for getting the min. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can reverse the sort direction to get the minimum instead of the maximum value:

```
 # Sort by myfield (ascending value) and return first document
 collection.find_one(sort=[("myfield", 1)])["myfield"]
```

This example assumes that:

- `myfield` is a numeric value (so the sort order makes sense to determine a minimum or maximum)
- `myfield` exists in the matching document returned (otherwise Python will report a `KeyError` when trying to reference a non-existent field).
- all documents in the collection have a `myfield` value (documents that have do not have a `myfield` value will sorted before the minimum numeric values)

To ensure your sort is based on documents that actually have a `myfield` value you can add [`$exists`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) to the query criteria:

```
 collection.find_one({"myfield": {"$exists": True}}, sort=[("myfield", 1)])["myfield"]
```

For more information on sorting see:

- [Use Indexes to Sort Query Results](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/)
- [What is the compare order for BSON types?](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#what-is-the-compare-order-for-bson-types)